# Window borders customization not affect all applications

Tags: gnome, 22.04, themes, gtk, borders

[Ubuntu 22.04 - GNOME 42]

I searched in the whole web, but I have not found a way to have every application to be managed by a window with a customizable border, both in terms of thickness and in terms of coloring.
I simply would like to have a 10px width green border around avery window applications.
Till now, the best I was able to get, is to create a `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` file with the following content:

```
decoration {
    borders: 10px solid #00FF00;
}
```

But this only affect few applications (the ones using standard gtk backend engine). Some applications, like **nautilus** and **firefox**, are not affected by this modification.
How can I do to have also these applications with a 10 px width green border around it?

[EDIT#1]

Here it is a screenshot of my Desktop where you can see the output from the `ls -al ~/.config/gtk-4.0/` command.

[image]

Also, from the same screenshot, you can notice that nautilus does not have any green border. The same for the Firefox window that I have replaced the snap version of the package with the PPA version.

Comment: Your installed Firefox may be the snap version. It will not obey the outside commands.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct with Ubuntu 22.04. The reason: some applications are using the [libadwaita](https://news.itsfoss.com/gnome-libadwaita-library/) library, which overwrites any themes (they simply ignore it).

There are two possible workarounds for this problem:

1. edit the `.profile` file in your home folder and add a line: `export GTK_THEME=yourtheme`. Log out and in again.
2. create a folder `.config/gtk-4.0` (.config exists in your home folder). Generate a link there: `ln -s /home/\<user>/.themes/yourtheme gtk.css` if your theme is installed locally, else use the `/usr/share/themes/yourtheme` as a source of your link.

This will (currently) circumvent the libadwaita constraints.

**This workaround will not work with applications installed by snap!**

In addition some applications are using their own theming (LibreOffice,FreeOffice and Firefox). The latter uses its own userChrome.css.

**UPDATE**

We can see different "ideas" of layouts: (Tweaks,gedit,nautilus & terminal):
[image: 1]]

which were generated with this css in `.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`:

```
window.csd:not(.popup)>decoration{
  border: 3px solid green;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px blue;
 }


/*
decoration,window.csd {
    border: 3px solid magenta;
}
*/

decoration {
border:3px solid yellow;
}

headerbar.titlebar {
    border-top: 3px solid magenta;
    border-left: 3px solid magenta;
    border-right: 3px solid magenta;
}
```

### Tweaks

1. window.csd decoration (blue)
2. headerbar with border (magenta)
3. an inner border (green)

### Gedit

1. window.csd decoration (blue)
2. an inner border (green)
3. not a header (it is a titlebar)

### Nautilus

1. window.csd decoration (blue)
2. Something, that is neither headbar nor titlebar

### Terminal

1. a decoration, but no window
2. a headerbar
3. no surrounding window.csd

None of the examples were gtk-4.0 - so if we focus on a big variety of implementations in the gtk-3.0 world.

So your best bet would be to use a box-shadow in window.csd and the decoration, which will handle most of the permutations. The decoration part will also draw the borders around a menu.Could be fixed with a `window.popup >decoration` css-selector.

Comment: I have tried both solutions, but neither work. After logging out and logging back in, there are still some apps (Firefox, nautilus, Calculator, LibreOffice,...) that don't have 10px thick green borders.

Comment: Yes. I forgot to mention that this will **NOT** work with applications installed by snap. But nautius should have those green border. I'll revise my answer.
Please post the output of `ls -la ~/.config/gtk-4.0/`

Comment: I just edit my original question with a new section (EDIT#1) answering to your comment @kanehekili .

Comment: Thanks for the updated version of the answer. With your version of the css for the gtk-3.0 based applications now I am able to have borders also with Nautilus. Still I do not have borders for Firefox window. Still I do not have (left, right and bottom) borders for LibreOffice window. I didn't know about the window.cds property. Where do I find a reference manual for understanding which elements of the GUI the gtk.css file is going to modifying? Is there a way to personalize also the LibreOffice and Firefox windows ?

Comment: If it worked, you should [accept the answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers). This way other readers will see that the answer is valid

Comment: Actually my original (real) problem is not solved. As I pointed out in my previous comment, even if your answer help me a bit to have a way to further customize window borders, the reality is that the tips you suggested do not works with all applications. Firefox still doesn't have customizable borders. I already told you that I do not have the snap version of the package, I did apply both workarounds, I copied the content of you gtk.css file and Firefox still not have colored borders. The same for LibreOffice.

Comment: Yes, doesn't work for me too. Sorry I couldn't help. Since these apps do not read the themes for their views (e.g. Firefox uses its own css->userChrome.css) then you don't have any chance to change anything.

Comment: Do you know any other either Linux distro or desktop environment suitable to have the customization I would like to have?

Comment: No -since the problem is not the distro but the application. If you'd write an app with hardcoded colors then nobody can change that color.  Applies also to QT Apps that run in GTK Environment (e.g VLC or Virtualbox) which rely on GTK2 there. Some elements are hardcoded in the qt5 translation process

Comment: I was thinking about a different approach... Supposed I am using X11 windowing system (Xorg), what if I try to manually recompile X11 package by myself ? I guess if I would able to hackerize X11 source code I could somehow cheat the system to make a green border appear around each newly instantiate window (doesn't matter if the window is created either by a SNAP app or not). Did you think would be feasible a such thing?

Comment: Very cool. Drop a note if done. Since borders belong to the windows and **not** to x11 that is quite a feat.

Comment: So, isn't there an action point into which you think could be feasible to modify source code and recompile any package that is responsible to draw basic logic for a new window (no matter which kind of backend is used to then decorize the window).... there should a part, in the system stack packages, that if modified the code, each new created window appear with a green border around it, even though that specific app is applying its own window decoration...